# EF doesn't save the whole complex object in db

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a EF code updating complex object (User object contains Address object). But when I want to update User's Address object properties while User object update process. After User's update process, updated User's properties are saved in db, but updated Address's properties are still the same in database (not saved). 
Where is the problem?
?

My code is here:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
    {

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Passwd { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Middlename { get; set; }
        public string Secondname { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobilenumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
        public string ActivationCode { get; set; }
        public StatusEnum? CurrentStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CurrentCreateSession { get; set; }
        public StatusEnum? PreviousStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PreviousCreateSession { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
 }


 public class Address : BaseEntity
    {
        //[JsonProperty("street")]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        //[JsonProperty("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        //[JsonProperty("zipcode")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        //[JsonProperty("country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
}

 public virtual void Edit(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

 public void SaveChanges()
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();            
        }
```

Comment: You need to update the Address and the User separately, or at least mark the Address as modified as well

Comment: @AllFallD0wn not with EF. It does the work. See answer below

Comment: @bubi Funny. OP just commented "Yes, it worked when I added line: Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.Address).State = EntityState.Modified" which is what I said..

Comment: @AllFallD0wn, in EF entity changes are tracked by the proxy.

Comment: @bubi: but it not working in my code. How to turn it on?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

User.Edit(someUserEntity);
```

these lines only indicate that `User` entity needs to be saved to the database. Any one to many relation will not be saved (in your case Address entities). You need to also change the states of child entities to `Modified` in order to update child entities.

Comment: Yes, it worked when I added line: `Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.Address).State = EntityState.Modified` to Edit method. Im wondering if I should create generic method using reflection to make sulution more generic.

Comment: But it not working without it. Waht you mean by `User.Edit(someUserEntity);` ?

Answer (score 0):

First question, why did you insert Edit method? Do you need a particular behaviour? Because EF knows if an entity has been edited or not. Also, take care because setting an entity as modified with optimistic lock (default EF behaviour) you could receive a concurrency exception.

Also a little suggestion, if Address is not shared between users mark it as complex type so you avoid the address table.

Anyway, supposing this

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Model6Context : DbContext
{
    public Model6Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    { }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

and that you did not specified any mapping
This piece of code

```
        Model6Context context = new Model6Context(connection);

        User user = new User
        {
            Firstname = "Bubi",
            Address = new Address
            {
                City = "Modena"
            }
        };

        context.Users.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();

        int userId = user.Id;

        context.Dispose();

        context = new Model6Context(connection);

        user = context.Users.First(u => u.Id == userId);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", user.Firstname, user.Address.City);

        user.Address.City = "Bologna";
        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Dispose();

        context = new Model6Context(connection);

        user = context.Users.First(u => u.Id == userId);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", user.Firstname, user.Address.City);
```

Produces this output

Bubi Modena
Bubi Bologna

What's the difference?

Comment: Generally my code is some more complex than I put here. We have a few layers.. and abstract generic reporsitory class to which method Edit belongs. But it seems not to working for more complex types like this one in this post. So Im trying to find generic solution for this problem (to be able to update add complex entities)

Comment: I used to work in that way when I was using Hibernate. With EF where I (we) can use only SaveChanges I changed the model. Using your approach you (and readers) could also think that only entities where you set EntityState.Modified are saved on the DB that is not true with EF. The proxy track the changes and if you modify an entity (readed from the DB so attached) the entity gets updated.